# O que fazer com contas fakes

Tags: debate, contas-usuário

O uso de múltiplas contas é uma prática que gera punição quando o usuário usa tal recurso para se beneficiar com *up-votes* entre as contas.

Queria saber o que ocorre quando um usuário cria uma conta fake também para se beneficiar com o intuito de receber ajudas mais 'atenciosas', seja com um nick 'sugestivo' ou fotos fake. Hoje me deparei com um avatar fake e me perguntei qual punição para isso. Há punição para tal ato?

Me refiro ao uso explícito de imagens de 3<sup>os</sup> sem autorização que são encontradas no instagram, facebook, twitter e afins.

Comment: Particularmente não gosto nada de usuários que usam avatares de outras **pessoas**. Por outro lado, eu *acho* que não há uma punição a não ser no caso de alguém reclamar o *copyright* ou se isso infringir alguma lei diretamente. No SOen já vi alguns usuários até famosos com avatares *fakes* do mesmo nível. Tudo o que eu sei é que os moderadores podem remover uma imagem nos casos onde isso se aplica. Só não vou responder diretamente porque acho que isso seria melhor tratado por alguém da equipe do SO.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars

Comment: @utluiz, eu também não gosto, na verdade até evito. Mas pensei que se tratando de um 'recurso' para atrair ajuda, alguma punição fosse aplicada. Aguardar qualquer atriz reclamar o *©* é estranho.

Comment: "Vixe" deletaram meus comentário? Será que falei besteira? :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que demos nomes aos bois kkkk

Comment: Então, mas só citei em um comentário o boi... kkkkkk... Os demais eu fiz antes de indicar os perfis. Segunda vez que fazem isto. Deixa pra lá.

Comment: Vou apontar outro perfil fake: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635 este usuário está se passando por um milionário fictício de uma série de TV.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, Sr. Burns não vale nada rs. Eu acho até que devia ter uma punição... Qualquer forma de ludibriar devia ser punida, mas fazer o que.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Eu concordo, mas acho que é daqueles tipos de coisas que não tem muito o que se fazer, não é uma coisa só da internet, é da cultura (eu acho). Ao meu ver as pessoas experientes que nem eu e você sabem detectar um perfil falso... O problema são pessoas sem noção que acham que estão conversando com a "princesa programadora" e ficam "puxando o saco" destes perfis falsos. Ao meu ver se os usuários sem noção não tivessem um pouco de senso acabam alimentando este tipo de pratica...

Comment: @PapaCharlie Concordo contigo punição ajudaria ... e de uns puxões de orelha nos "puxas sacos" também rs

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Se passar por outra pessoas é crime... Talvez um dia o SO adote uma regra mais rigorosa quanto a isso sem precisar reivindicar *©* - os casos são claro. Enfim... que siga o barco.

Comment: @PapaCharlie é verdade, infelizmente é deixar seguir mesmo.

Comment: Putz achei que tava com moral com as novinha do site, fui dibrado igual ao ronaldo...