# O que fazer com usuários fakes?

Tags: debate, usuarios

Estou fazendo essa pergunta, pois procurei no meta, e encontrei [essa mesma pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2476/o-que-fazer-com-contas-fakes), porém não existe resposta. Partindo deste ponto, me deparei recentemente com a mesma situação. Um usuário [(esse usuário)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30003/kelly-soares) usando claramente uma foto fake, que pode ser comprovada por base [desta pesquisa.](https://www.google.com.br/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitn1dJRFEW5HtGlblmI-W1TI9N5qPuBOkQurkGJ0NGaxr_1o1V1yc-wiqiDR1hhRIf2tdiyyU7ICAt6kGNvOvcVoHPr0KdPi7cmiG8YDfeoXZUslrfnh1YshT2zE4t_1vytTqCL4FA5h08erO9TPhySiopyk84QcShgcgQlSL3-gQdSlHf4NEnbEdrWaSz_1Xu6_178-OMbCgJV2pfNZLtEENtdoLGS_1VgQhHp2vl0UCvcZhvV4dHZmjFT72E7PYL74cMnOeFKbSjvU_1x1CE8EHy9P5gf3soie1uc6dhUWa4w3Pj1mtVpp43J13iz_1XoVYSHsQWtWQsVG8EAO0OpXwThcritxQ6c4Ij7zDwHNWpMwnBg6NYBsB0rjhaZEWIr1_184yTtx9QgpOetBwnBrGl-sYyPBAQRCnh1L-62id2cjungANoc7uXFxsexCU944bWLYsSxxevrDjQeReIzoVkzUQ_1gWk1iuDIKGVEbW85w0Ymwm9kZutp4ZL_1JrgtsNETBEB9ph61KP5_1nXyfX4SLH2Nv2_1fhv-Ctkc0Q4PcSlvOrO1AVSOKUS08DWVGf8sZfJJaoYKbPsacIzOt7JK4_1ZX1JDBSk1ElE2U10jcXV4W4aAVZ0ube1ptVXKNjClpVTUI5mzXC7zpfBNv_1gMU8EiV6mbQxwFdLpBcaxR3zFTFVry5gNHIJjKlmB9n6Iyz0LZrmemJ9Z_1ZtiAAHJciMJwf8-8H6iCFMETZPZwe7nedYYCvWoire3xKmwUS8UPajdsmV9ewfxVuihB1HPCml8jKmcPscdcsD0qfYEVqakyYqmtT2EWsQ1Ygq7udEMfTzXaINVXKWneVSpzvVfp1HrKdfXxaDcsOJvdkCB9O535KFXqqqx9EmGomYfkUbcKuE9J48gW6D_1XXZT4gbUK7ufXU-_17pqVOMIIPAidXJfjPaz-ty7bhezdY2QZaYFUjozAK_10heFqADDsV0FObkDV_1izagEpmiwRygYixvdRCJkBLwonS_1EjqQNgx4eLvZlfljqpwZyHcLjDZZYJMbII3CSGoRI_1a8Er5XsdqSS4qjCn-X8K2WThYJvdI4eODlsDtZT3V3xtQQsZckv57EvO8BlOkhkzar5Jb8CQu-vRJ4RvqhAt1HxON_1-HC0ZrHCigwCbao1lsZ7JFr7HRYAXZhtU1HmnvGbslphi5nHPnHNvxYgbuU3gU0PdV_1PEAFJZI24E6dY0anEnrBlrTpKXzYgwV5kcDROldsrKzooiScNt5_1DvqH7yzOC4XUM08dz7B6ya_161MR3K1gIVgA6EjvjFzv7iQUiNORcuIrHpHr6X_1tgD-nyn7zR5iO1yIN6pMmzM0yfpagSByX8VdJhDGX_1cQyNfbBXitvKjti7ppNnyExI49OCykikvLnLG7Z8K-DLl35OHdb1fq_1npRVACpPpF9kbCHysnDBXlWXb-jMW3AbpY8RcqGnXwJ10LLTcsprecyIbCmoQxantiYyoOqpSaoftsBbwYPrCQgchsNQPQKuNd-aTh0rhl990uQTWjDH88kRzPRdvTZ&hl=pt) Não sei a questão do nome, estou me referindo a foto, seja lá por qual motivo está utilizando.

Eu particularmente fiquei desanimado em responder as perguntas deste usuário com base no decorrer das perguntas, mas por parecer se tratar de um fake, me desanimou mais ainda.

Com isso, vem minha dúvida:

**Existe alguma punição por criar usuários fakes?**

Se não, como proceder com usuários que "parecem" ser fakes apenas para "tentarem" se beneficiar no site?

Comment: Eu acho zoado essas coisas, mas fazer o que... não é o primeiro, nem será o último. Entretanto acho que precisamos nos preocupar com as perguntas, afinal é isso que movimenta essa comunidade. Se o usuário faz boas perguntas e dá boas respostas, não vejo problema. A imagem é um detalhe :P

Comment: @renan Eu concordo com você, tanto que na pergunta eu afirmo que me "desanimei" em responder as perguntas do usuário pela qualidade, e não por ser tratar de um fake ou não. Porém, hoje existem N formas de criar uma pergunta no site, nem precisa se registrar para isso. Então me fiz essa pergunta.

Comment: O usuário não importa, importa a qualidade da pergunta. Só tem problema se a foto for explícita, de incitação ao ódio ou tentativa de personificar outro usuário. No SOen funciona muito bem esse truque da foto sexy como avatar para atrair respostas para perguntas mal-feitas, kkkkk

Comment: Revisei a última pergunta da super-moça e mal-feita não está, tinha problemas de formatação... acho que tem código demais e debug de menos...

Comment: A foto foi removida

Comment: @EduardoSeixas aparentemente a foto continua com o AP. Eu não consigo realmente confirmar, pois algumas fotos são bloqueadas pelo firewall da empresa, mas me afirmaram que a foto ainda consta no perfil.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Infelizmente as pessoas tem compreensões diferentes do que é realmente um *fake*, por exemplo eu uso a foto de um desenho e uso meu nome real, mesmo assim já fui acusado de ser *"fake"*.

Tem usuários aqui que não usam nomes reais (a maioria), entretanto isto não os torna *fakes* do meu ponto de vista, mesmo o tal usuário(a) do caso citado na sua pergunta.

O problema ao meu ver é o uso de uma foto pra se promover se valendo da "ignorância" (falta de conhecimento) dos demais usuários sobre sub-celebridades (geralmente não tão conhecida), quero dizer o usuário(a) usa a foto de uma pessoa atraente que muitas vezes é "famosa" (ou mesmo de pessoas desconhecidas) com o intuito de promover as duvidas e ganhar a atenção de outros usuários para ajudar com a sua duvida, o problema aqui é esta atitude e não se é "fake" ou não (já que fake pode ser interpretado de várias maneiras).

**Pra mim** estes usuários(as) nem fazem tão mal assim, o problema realmente são os outros usuários *sem noção* que acreditam que a pessoa da foto é realmente o usuário que esta lá do outro lado do computador e por este motivo postagens com problemas não são fechadas ou deletadas e ainda por cima recebem atenção quando não deviam, resumindo:

- O problema é o uso das fotos de sub-celebridades (ou foto de uma pessoa atraente que não é ela) com o intuito de ganhar visibilidade
- Usuários que ficam tentando agradar tal usuário sendo prestativos, quando as perguntas geralmente estão fora do escopo ou deveriam ser fechadas por outros motivos
- Se o usuário(a) que usa fotos de sub-celebridades (ou foto de uma pessoa atraente que não é ela) mas ainda sim faz uma boa pergunta, então não é tão problema, já que o mais importante aqui são as **perguntas** e **respostas**, não os **perfis** dos usuários.
- Não existe punição, já que os sites do *Stack Overflow* não obrigam ninguém usar a identidade real e fake pode ser interpretado de várias maneiras.
- Mesmo que houve-se alguma punição apenas por ser "um fake", o usuário ainda poderia argumentar que a foto é de uma namorada(o) ou que ele(a) é fã da pessoa que usou a foto, o que invalidaria qualquer acusação.

### O que fazer?

**Nada**, simplesmente veja a qualidade da pergunta, se for ruim quase sempre (existem exceções) esta *fora do escopo* > *Não pode ser reproduzido* ou então *não esta clara o suficiente* ou *ampla demais*. Como eu disse pra mim os piores são os outros usuários que ficam dando atenção pras perguntas que deveriam ser fechadas, infelizmente não há muito o que fazer:

O melhor é comentar a pergunta e dizer algo como por exemplo:

> *Votei em fechar porque esta fora do escopo ...*

Se for uma resposta sinalize ou delete (*[pra deletar a resposta precisa ter -1 e você precisa ter 20.000 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)*), acaso sinalize ou tenha votado pra fechar *na fila*, comente em seguida (geralmente o voto pra fechar já tem um comentário) algo como:

> *Sua resposta não responde a pergunta por tal motivo ...*

Acredito que isto fará os demais usuários pensarem antes de participar de algo que deveria estar fechado enquanto não atende ao padrão de qualidade minimo.

Se a pergunta estiver dentro do escopo e tiver o minimo de qualidade exigido *pela comunidade*, então responda ou deixe outro responder.

*Se notar* algum tipo de abuso por parte do usuário como exemplos citados pelo [@brasofilo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4429/o-que-fazer-com-usu%C3%A1rios-fakes#comment13961_4429):

> ... Só tem problema se a foto for explícita, de incitação ao ódio ou tentativa de personificar outro usuário... – brasofilo

Você **deve** sinalizar pra um moderador na própria pergunta do tal usuário e explicar no campo de texto o problema que tal usuário esta causando:

<kbd>[image: Sinalizar]</kbd>

De resto é ter [*paciência*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je-RTYbzoEk).

Comment: Bom, e o cara que responde uma pergunta por causa das pernas de uma foto certamente não vai saber responder direito. rsrs No fim o que importa é a qualidade da pergunta: é boa fica aberta, atrai a atenção de quem interessa (os especialistas) e as respostas. É ruim fecha-se, independentemente de raça, cor, credo, pernas ou opção sexual.  O que importa (repita pausadamente, como um mantra) são as perguntas e as respostas.

Comment: Exatamente *são as perguntas e as respostas* :)

Comment: Vou contar um segredo pra vocês: Meu nome *não é*  OnoSendai. **Dum dum duuuuuum**!

Comment: @OnoSendai https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx_32iIuEyQ

Comment: Tá vendo, Meta-Meta. O @Ono usa foto "real" mas confessa que o nome não é o dele. O Guilherme usa avatar de Mangá mas jura que se chama assim mesmo. Não sei não, vou revisar meu perfil pra confirmar que eu sou eu mesmo!

Comment: @brasofilo você usa foto de fantasminha sorridente!

Comment: O real problema, no meu caso, é que desanima você querer ajudar "além" da resposta. As vezes você chama o usuário no chat ou leva alguma outra informação para ajudar a esclarecer o problema, mas quando se trata de um "fake", como neste caso, perde-se o interesse. Bom, pelo menos no meu caso.

Comment: Mas sua resposta esclareceu os pontos onde estava com dúvidas, obrigado por compartilhar sua opinião.

Comment: Tenho conhecido o @bfavaretto pessoalmente, posso garantir que o nome dele não é bfavaretto e ele não é um desenho... Mas até onde eu sei, o bigown pode mesmo ser um olho!