# Empresas podem criar perfil no StackOverflow? (um perfil com múltiplos usuários)

Tags: debate, perfil, contas-usuário

Imagine que uma empresa a fim de angariar novos talentos, ou simplesmente por uma ação de *branding* crie um "perfil comunitário" no StackOverflow, e incentive que seus funcionários contribuam respondendo as mais diversas perguntas.

**EX:** Imagine que a IBM crie uma conta no SOpt e que a senha seja compartilhada entre os diversos empregados da empresa onde todos respondem em nome do perfil IBM.

Isso seria permitido? Viola algum termo de uso? Ou empresas podem criar perfil e botar uma equipe para responder as questões?

Comment: Não sei se é permitido hoje, mas no passado, ao menos para alguns casos já foi: https://stackoverflow.com/users/69258/datanucleus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Copiando [daqui](https://stackexchange.com/legal) (grifo próprio):

> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., **not a corporate entity**) at least 13 years of age.

Traduzindo do inglês-legalês para o português-legalês e então para o português entendível:

> O usuário garante ao Stack Exchange que ele é uma pessoa (ou seja, **não uma corporação**) com pelo menos 13 anos de idade.

No passado, até 2014 ou 2015, ter contas corporativas era permitido no Stack Overflow ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69258/datanucleus)). Não sei ao certo porque houve uma mudança nessa política, mas provavelmente devem ter havido diversos problemas com contas corporativas. Imagino (mas não tenho certeza) que tenham sido os seguintes:

- Sockpupetting.
- Um dos usuários controlando a conta causa problemas que acabam atrapalhando a todos os controladores coletivamente.
- Votos de contas corporativas não refletem exatamente opinião pessoal.
- Ao conversar em comentários ou em chat, principalmente em coisas com opiniões um pouco mais fortes (críticas postadas em comentários de perguntas e respostas, por exemplo), fica difícil saber-se qual seria o comportamento ou reação mais adequados. Imagina você recebendo um comentário do usuário *IBM* dizendo que há um problema na sua resposta porque você deveria usar o método X ao invés do método Y.

Comment: +1 por eu aprender um termo novo: `Sockpupet` :p

Answer (score 6):

> um perfil com múltiplos usuários

Não, isto não existe atualmente.

> Imagine que a IBM crie uma conta no SOpt e que a senha seja compartilhada entre os diversos empregados da empresa onde todos respondem em nome do perfil IBM.

Veja que o perfil dos sites da rede não lhe obrigam em nenhum momento você se identificar como uma pessoa real, nem fornecer dados reais, a não ser seu e-mail, mas também não afirmam em nada sobre ser um e-mail corporativo ou não.

Lendo os termos em geral (não consegui entender tudo ainda, provavelmente nem a metade :P): https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service

Noto que o que você aceita é sobre o que você compartilha aqui, é mais sobre a comunidade do que tipo de usuário.

Então diria que o tipo do usuário é irrelevante, o interesse é o que ele pode trazer e compartilhar com o site. Mas talvez alguém da *staff* possa lhe orientar melhor.

O uso da conta de maneira compartilhada ao meu ver é relativamente irrelevante, desde que "toda" equipe tenha ponderação ao postar coisas, se um agir de má fé com o site com certeza será a conta a sofrer a punição e todos irão ser prejudicados.

Comment: "Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age" ==> bem, exige-se ser um indivíduo, nem mesmo dois irmãos poderiam compartilhar uma conta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado e quem vai investigar isto? :)

Comment: é tão feio mentir... não podemos mais nem confiar nas pessoas?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pra mim a situação é tal como a dos fakes: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4429/3635 - se usar devidamente e for produtivo não tem nem como criticar o uso desta forma.

Comment: Como comunidade não vejo porquê barrar, mas no contratuês/jurisdiquês traduzido pode implicar em desativar a conta por conta da rede. Não vejo porquê tomarmos ações, assim como na maioria dos "bons fakes", então estamos de acordo. Mas é uma questão de segurança do usuário saber essa limitação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado concordo plenamente!